# Check if multiple datetime are same in php foreach

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime, php-5.6

I want to split items which have same date and different date.

```
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item)
{
$pickupDateTime = $item->getCartPickupDate().' '.$itemgetCartPickupTime(); 
$pickupDateTime = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($pickupDateTime)) //2018-03-09 6:03:00 or 2018-03-09 21:10:00

// Split items here with same Date //

if(Dates are Same Condition){
$items_normal[]= $item->getProductId();
}else
{
//If Dates Are diffrent
$ites_special[]= $item->getProductId();
}

}
```

Need to compare if dates are same in first if condition and in else part the items which have different dates.

Look at the following arrays, in this I have same date and time, I need to club those which have same date and time. In below example, the 3rd one must be come under first Array as it has different time i.e. 6:05 instead of 6:03

```
    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 742
            [qty] => 1
            [date] => 03/09/2018
            [time] => 06:03 AM
            [tax] => 0
            [splinst] => null
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 743
            [qty] => 1
            [date] => 03/09/2018
            [time] => 06:03 AM
            [tax] => 0
            [splinst] => null
        )

)

Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 744
            [qty] => 1
            [date] => 03/09/2018
            [time] => 06:03 AM
            [tax] => 0.12
            [splinst] => null
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 757
            [qty] => 1
            [date] => 03/09/2018
            [time] => 06:05 AM
            [tax] => 0.25
            [splinst] => null
        )

)
```

Comment: For that you can save daets in array and use `is_array()` to check same date

Comment: how can we check in_array for same date object?

Comment: Do you have only one date which is the same?

Comment: no, multiple datetime can be same

Answer (score 0):

You could store the date in keys into an array to group items :

```
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item)
{
    $pickupDateTime = $item->getCartPickupDate().' '.$itemgetCartPickupTime(); 
    $pickupDateTime = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($pickupDateTime)) //2018-03-09 6:03:00 or 2018-03-09 21:10:00
    $items_special[$pickupDateTime][] = $item->getProductId();
}
foreach ($items_special as $date => $items) {
    if (count($items) > 1) {
        $items_normal = $items ;
        unset($items_special[$date]);
        break;
    }
}
$items_special = array_values($items_special);
```

So, `$items_special` will look like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 757
            [qty] => 1
            [date] => 03/09/2018
            [time] => 06:05 AM
            [tax] => 0.25
            [splinst] => null
        )

)
```

And `$items_normal` will look like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 742
            [qty] => 1
            [date] => 03/09/2018
            [time] => 06:03 AM
            [tax] => 0
            [splinst] => null
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 743
            [qty] => 1
            [date] => 03/09/2018
            [time] => 06:03 AM
            [tax] => 0
            [splinst] => null
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 744
            [qty] => 1
            [date] => 03/09/2018
            [time] => 06:03 AM
            [tax] => 0.12
            [splinst] => null
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DateTime object:

```
$pickupDateTime = $item->getCartPickupDate().' '.$itemgetCartPickupTime(); 
$pickupDateTime = new DateTime($pickupDateTime);
```

You can compare two DateTime objects which each other:

```
if ($dateTimeObject1 == $dateTimeObject2) {
    // both have same date and time
}
```

Be aware that you should not use strict comparison (===) here as it would check if it is the same object and not if the DateTime is the same.

If you need to compare only the date and ignore the time you can call setTime on both objects to reset the time to 0:

```
$dateTimeObject1->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$dateTimeObject2->setTime(0, 0, 0);
if ($dateTimeObject1 == $dateTimeObject2) {
    // both have the same date
}
```

Comment: need to compare complete datetime object